# catch clicks on the 'x' button using Tk Tcl

Tags: tcl, exit, tk-toolkit

I'm using Tcl/Tk to build a GUI, for Linux environment and I saw that it's possible to "catch" a press on the 'x' button of the window (The button on the top right corner that closes the program).

How can I catch those events?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To take control of requests to delete a window, configure a suitable protocol handler:

```
wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW {
    if {[tk_messageBox -message "Quit?" -type yesno] eq "yes"} {
       exit
    }
}
```

The default behavior (i.e., if the protocol handler is the *empty* string) is to just `destroy` the toplevel to which the request was made.

Comment: How can I call all destructors of all child objects that have been created?

Answer (score 5):

Bind to the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` "protocol message" using the `wm protocol` [command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.htm#M44).

Also note that if you just want track window destruction (on a higher level), just [bind](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm#M5) to its `<Destroy>` event.

Comment: Binding to `<Destroy>` on toplevels can be tricky, since you also get it for the sub-widgets of the toplevel (due to general event handling rules).

Comment: @Donal Fellows, agreed. One trick is to embed our own window name in the callback and then skip those bogus calls, like in `bind $w <Destroy> [list cb $w %W]; proc cb {w1 w2} { if {$w1 ne $w2} return; # otherwise do whatever is needed }`

Comment: I've done that in the past. The other way is to see whether the event window is the same as the toplevel of the event window: `if {"%W" eq [winfo toplevel %W]} ...` (or equivalent in a procedure).